# How to react to a message attachment discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

So what I am trying to do is, my discord bot listens for attachments then takes them and sends them to a particular channel, I want it to also react it with  and  now I saw some solutions but they require message id and channel id, my channel id would remain the same but my message id would change every time I send an attachment how do I make it so it reacts to the attachment into that channel

My code:-

```
client.on("message", async message => {
  message.attachments.forEach((attachment) => {
    if (attachment.width && attachment.height) {
      if (message.author.bot) return
      let yes = attachment
      const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "llllllounge")
      channel.send(yes)
        .then(() => attachment.react(''))
        .then(() => attachment.react(''))
    }
  });
})
```

I have tried `yes.react('')` but it does not work and replies with `yes.react is not a function`
Would be grateful if someone helps me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Channel#send` returns a promise. Meaning we can use an `asynchronous function` in order to define the channel sending method using `await` (Send the message before defining it), and have our bot react to the newly sent message.

#### Final Code

```
client.on("message", message => {
  message.attachments.forEach(async (attachment) => {
    if (attachment.width && attachment.height) {
      if (message.author.bot) return
      let yes = attachment
      const channel = client.channels.cache.find(channel => channel.name === "llllllounge")
      const msg = await channel.send(yes)
        await msg.react('')
        msg.react('')
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: Hey it gives this error now const msg = await channel.send(yes) is only available in an async function

Comment: And also when I run the code it says msg.react() is not a function if i remove the await

Comment: Both should now be fixed.

Comment: No problem, I'd recommend accepting my edit :)